# Java: Is the value of a String's characters (in bytes) constant?

Tags: java, character-encoding, char, byte

**TL;DR**: In Java, will casting a character obtained from a String via the `charAt` method to a byte always yield the same value?

I am reading files which are encoded with arbitrary (unknown to us) character encodings. I need to parse these files and look for certain words, e.g. "TAG". I placed certain restrictions on the file contents, such as "when looking for a tag, the bytes for "TAG" must be the same as their ASCII representation".

For example, suppose I have the following file:
`0x00 0x11 0x22 0x33 0x54 0x41 0x47 0x77 0x88 0x99 0xaa 0xbb`
Since the ASCII values for T, A and G are respectively `0x54`, `0x41` and `0x47`, I can find "TAG" in the file by parsing the bytes themselves.
`0x00 0x11 0x22 0x33`**`0x54 0x41 0x47`**`0x77 0x88 0x99 0xaa 0xbb`

However, I need to hard-code the value of the bytes I am looking for. To do this, I call `String`'s `charAt(int i)` method and cast the char to a byte.

Here is, for example, how I would verify an arbitrary byte (called `b`) for the byte representation of 'T':
`String tag = "TAG";`
`char t = tag.charAt(0);`
`if ((byte)t == b){`
        `//magic goes here, such as comparing the 'A' and the 'G'`
`}`
*Note: the code is not actually like that, and the verification algorithm is much more elegant.*

This works fine on my local machine. However, this will be run on machines which may contain very strange encodings. What worries me is whether casting a character obtained with `charAt` to a byte might yield a different value depending on the machine. I know that Java always encodes `char`s with the UTF-16 character encoding, but I am worried that when converting from a String to a character and then to a byte might yield strange results.

So, in short, will casting a character obtained from a String via the `charAt` method to a byte always yield the same value? Or will it depend on an external factor?

Thanks for your help!

***Note**: I cannot hard-code the bytes themselves (in, for example, a byte array) since they can be very very long and may be changed very often in the future.*

Comment: string's charAt will always return a 16 bit UTF-16 character, which will always be the same when you cast it to a byte.

Comment: How are you reading the file into strings if you do not know the encoding?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I am not reading the file into Strings. Like I said, I am reading the file in bytes directly. I use hard-coded Strings to know what to find in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.string.charAt` will always return a 16 bit UTF-16 character, which will always be the same when you cast it to a byte, though because `char` is a 16-bit unsigned data type, casting it as an 8-bit signed `byte` might give you unwanted behavior. However if your source data is ASCII, you will get exactly the type of behavior you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `charAt (int)` returns a Java defined char type (UTF-16) and is therefore always the same casted to `byte`.

In contrary `String.getBytes()` returns the bytes depending either on the specified charset or on the default charset of the OS if none is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of a char to a byte with `(byte)` will give you the same result on all system.

However, it is very rare that you need to mix `char` and `byte`.  You should really use one or the other. Mixing the concepts can lead to confusion as you suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typecasting them directly, you could use the `Character.codePointAt(char c)` method. This should guarantee you the same result every time.